# Is it possible to attach an html report in email body using protractor?

Tags: javascript, html, protractor, report

I am creating 2 HTML reports using protractor. But while attaching it to email body its not looking visually good. Is it possible to create a table report so that I can attach it to the email body?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('D:/CaseQualityCheck/script/result/Report.html');
fs.writeFileSync('D:/CaseQualityCheck/script/result/Report.html', '<table id = "table-casedetail">\n' + '<tr>\n' + '<th>Case No.</th>\n' + '<th>Case Name</th>\n' + '<th>Version</th>\n' + '<th>Problem Type</th>\n' + '</tr>\n' + content + '</table>\n', 'utf8');
```